# Using the Validation Block of Enterprise Library with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

We've used the Validation Block of MS Enterprise Library for some time with great success in conjunction with custom DALs but we've recently started using the Entity Framework and can't get the Validation Block to work with it.  The objects are dynamically created in EF and putting attributes on top of them will simply get wiped out when the models are re-genned.

Can these two co-exist?  If not, does anyone have any recommendations for what validation library/simple rules engine would be a good candidate to use along with EF?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to flag your favorite answer ;-).

Answer (score 2):

You need a validator which supports a "buddy class" (like [this example for Dynamic Data](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/08/10/AspNetMvc20BuddyClassesMetadataType.aspx)). [This seems to be a work in progress for VAB](http://entlib.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=69618). I can't find an example of anyone actually using it yet, but it might work.

Answer (score 2):

Validation Application Block supports the concept of configuration based validation. This way you can separate your generated domain entities from validation. You can use the Enterprise Library configuration tool for this. Simply right-click on your configuration file and start adding validation configuration.

I advise you to read the VAB Hands on Lab document (ValidationHOL.pdf) which is included in the [Hands On Lab download](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2C34A9CB-17CF-4AEC-8DE6-EEACBBB74413&displaylang=en). After reading that document, read [this article](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=46). It explains how to integrate VAB with Entity Framework.

Good luck.